# migrate from MSQL to SQL with table relationship intact

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I migrated the database successfully from MSQL to MYSQL using MySQL Workbench however it deleted the table relationships(foreign key). Is there a way if i can migrate the database including the table relationship..

I have over 350 tables in the database and its difficult to manually write the foreign key(if existed) for each table..

Comment: you have to lookup into some tool

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/ and http://www.convert-in.com/mss2sql.htm and https://dbconvert.com/mssql/mysql/